# How do I change image of a slider closed in another function?

Tags: javascript

what I have in here is a simple slider with two images. Is there a way to change the `var file` of `imageSwap()` when the counter hits 12?

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
var timer1 = 0;
var timer2 = 0;

function imageSwap(id) {
  var img = document.getElementById("app" + id);

  img.src = "red.png";
  img.classList.add("selected");

  var count = document.querySelectorAll(".selected").length;

  console.log(count);
  if (count == 12) {
    // Change var file image of function Change()
  }
}

function hide() {
  $("#slider").fadeOut(500);
}

function change() {
  number++;
  if (number > 2) number = 1;

  var file = '<img src="tree' + number + '.png" />';

  document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = file;
  $("#slider").fadeIn(500);

  timer1 = setTimeout("change()", 5000);
  timer2 = setTimeout("hide()", 4500);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not with the way things are above, where `file` is completely private to `change`. You can do *something*, but it's not clear what you really want to do. Change it **how**, for instance? And where/when is `imageSwap` called?

Comment: Side note: Never pass strings into `setTimeout`. Pass in functions. In the above, that would be `setTimeout(change, 5000);` and `setTimeout(hide, 4500);`.

Comment: `file` isn't even used in the `change()` function? Also, if you need to access a variable in more than one function, simply move its declaration to the outer scope, like for instance `number` or `timer1`.

Comment: ```imageSwap(id)``` is called out onload by body. Problem is that i can't make ```var file``` global because it uses that ```if```. I am beginner at this stuff and can't think of solution by myself, after hours of research i just couldn't find anything.

Comment: How can i possibly stop the loop so i could just insert an image in the slider place?